# When a probability density function is defined to be finite?

Tags: probability, distributions, density-function, gamma-distribution

In "Pattern recognition and machine learning" by Cristopher Bishop, Chapter 2.3.6 (pag. 100) says that

> The gamma distribution has a finite integral if $a>0$, and the
>   distribution itself is finite if $a \ge 1$

When a probability density function is defined to be *finite*? Can you make me an example of a finite pdf, and one of an infinite pdf?

Comment: This statement from Bishop is incorrect in that the Ga$(a,1)$ density is finite on its support $(0,\infty)$ albeit unbounded when $0<a<1$.

Comment: @Xi'an What do you mean by "finite in an (infinite) support"?

Comment: I did not write "finite in an (infinite) support"...

Comment: @Xi'an well, what does it mean that "the Ga(a,1) density is *finite*"? That its image lies in a bounded vectorial space, that is, that $Ga(\cdot): \mathcal{R} \to [a,b]$ where $a \neq \pm \infty$ and $b \neq \pm \infty$?

Comment: @Xi'an because BruceET is using "finite" to mean what you mean by "unbounded" (and thus for $0<a<1$ would not be finite, in that terminology)

Comment: As stated in [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/440313/14893), to [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/146136/14893), $f$ is finite if $$\forall x\in\text{supp}(f)\quad f(x)<\infty$$[[Elias Stein's Real Analysis](https://amzn.to/2XPWnPG), at the beginning of Chapter 4.1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you mean the function $f(x) = \frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha - 1}e^{-\beta x},$ for $x > 0,$ and $0$ otherwise, as stated in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution). There it is stated that parameters $\alpha >0$ and $\beta > 0,$ assuring that $f(x)$ is a density function.

If that is true,
then the integral $J = \int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$ converges and the constant
factor $\frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}$ is chosen so that $J = 1.$
That together with the fact that $f(x) \ge 0,$  makes
$f(x)$ the density function of a probability distribution.

Furthermore, if $\alpha \ge 1,$ then $f(x) \le M$ for some finite $M$ and for all $x\in (0,\infty).$
By contrast, for $0 < \alpha < 1,$ the function $f(x)$ has a vertical asymptote at $0.$

By way of illustration we show density functions of the distributions
$\mathsf{Beta}(\alpha = 1/2, \beta = 1)$ on the left, $\mathsf{Beta}(\alpha = 1, \beta = 1)$ in the center, and $\mathsf{Beta}(\alpha = 2, \beta = 1)$ at the right.

[image]

*Note:* The parameter $\alpha$ is called a *shape* parameter because
it determines the fundamental shape of the density curve. As you can see from the right-hand plot above, the density function has one inflection point for $\alpha = 2.$ Can you find a value of $\alpha$ above which the density function has two inflection points (and thus a 'left tail')?

**Addendum:** Plots for three additional values of $\alpha:$

[image]

Comment: ah ok, so the distribution is *finite* if the image of the pdf lives in a finite vectorial space. For your question, I guess for $\alpha=3$ has two inflection points?

Comment: Many commonly used density functions are are unbounded (often near $x=0).$ In computation that is sometimes an inconvenience, but does not interfere with the practical use of the probability model. // Yes, on $\alpha = 3.$ There are 5 distinct behaviors of gamma distn's near 0, taking into account asymptotic values & slopes. // I would not want my books judged by single sentences taken out of context, but the sentence you quote is far too 'chatty' and colloquial and could be misinterpreted. Unless a function integrates to unity it can't be the density function of a probability dist'n.